# Need to extract website localstorage every second

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to extract browser local storage for one of the key value every second.
I am pretty much ok with any solution with any tool

The website which i am trying is having a local storage with the key "ABC" which is updating every second & i need to extract every second data & need to store it somewhere (may be database or write in some file) for my code to use.

Is this possible ?
If yes please advise how to do that ?

Note - I already tried some of the plugin etc., but plugin's are helpless in this since that is extracting one time data. I want this to be more dynamic & fetch data every second

Comment: You should use this javascript function : [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: It sounds like you should look into something like WebSockets instead of using local storage.